# Site redirection of recently acquired domains works fine from external network but fails inside internal network

Tags: internal-dns, website, cloudflare

We have recently acquired 04 domains and configured 301 site redirection for those sites to our company site and it works fine from external network. However, the redirection doesn't work from inside corporate network.

The new domains resolve to the same IP address from both external & internal network. Example;

a.com - 209.17.xxx.xxx

a-a.com - 209.17.xxx.xxx

b.com - 209.17.xxx.xxx

b-b.com - 209.17.xxx.xxx

My existing domain is same as my active directory domain and our company site is accessible from both external & internal network.

Name:    [www.xxx.com.cdn.cloudflare.net](http://www.xxx.com.cdn.cloudflare.net)
Addresses:

2606:xx00:xx00::xx12:xx83

2606:xx00:xx00::xx40:xx7d

172.64.xxx.xxx

104.18.xx.xxx

Aliases:
[www.xxx.com](http://www.xxx.com)

[www.xxx.com.dxcloud.episerver.net](http://www.xxx.com.dxcloud.episerver.net)

I have created a Forward Lookup Zone in our AD integrated DNS for one of the acquired domains and created CNAME & A records pointing to our company site, but it didn't help.

What am I missing to make it work? Any help is appreciated.